# Why do I see repeated https requests from the same socket.io client?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I was looking at my logs, and it seems on occasion, I have a great many socket.io get requests from the same user. Is this normal behavior or did I do something wrong?

```
12:24:29 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU34x"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:30 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU38N"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:37 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU4Xd"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:45 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU6oG"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:45 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU6nE"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:51 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU8QL"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:24:58 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUA4O"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:04 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUBXz"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:04 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUBY-"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:04 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUBZq"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:04 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUBay"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:12 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUDPB"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:12 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUDNc"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
12:25:12 method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwUDOU"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=233 protocol=https
```

Everything seems to be working, but occasionally my server seems to be hammered by these requests.

Comment: Those just look like the initial https connection that starts a socket.io connection request.   You would have to determine if the ones that are within the same second are all coming from the same client and if so, why the client is doing that?  It's probably not something you can determine from the server.  There are cases where a mismatched socket.io version will cause repeated connection failures, but the bit of logging we see doesn't appear to indicate that.

Comment: the thing is, this is constant, at times. all from the same ip. so perhaps i have something setup wrong?

Comment: The `transport=polling` aspect of the URL appears to be a client that is trying to only use http polling, not the webSocket transport.  That seems misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I fixed the initialization on the client side and now seems to be working smoothly.

Comment: The question in your title is equivalent to asking how long is a piece of string.

Comment: A better title would be something like "Why do I see repeated https requests from the same socket.io client?"

Comment: i changed the title as suggested

Answer (score 1):

The `transport=polling` aspect of the URL:

```
/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NnwU34x
```

appears to be a client that is trying to only use http polling, not the webSocket transport. That seems misconfigured and will cause repeated http(s) connections in a polling fashion to regularly check for new messages rather than making a persistent webSocket connection for the transport.

You should make sure that you aren't forcing the transport to polling in some way in the client and are allowing the webSocket transport to be used.

Answer (score 0):

on the client side, I replaced io.connect("url") with just io.connect() and it seemed to have solved the issue.

Thanks @jfriend00 - [How many socket.io requests to server per user is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559097/how-many-socket-io-requests-to-server-per-user-is-too-many?noredirect=1#comment122949336_69559097) - for confirming my initialization appeared to be misconfigured.

Comment: What `url` were you using in the client?

Comment: ```https://www.<mydomain>```

Comment: That's odd that that would cause a problem.

Comment: if I recall correctly, heroku does something odd with https connections, so perhaps that's the cause?